# I want to read a text file and store the data in array with try-catch condition then convert it into format in php?

Tags: php, arrays, csv, try-catch

I want to read the text file and read it in PHP then splits into arrays and showing data in another text file. After that, I have converted this file to format and then any user can download the converted CSV file. I have attached a file herewith [File.txt](http://textuploader.com/djwxd)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body> 
 
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <h2>IRIS to ASB Conversion</h2>
        <div class="panel panel-default">
          <div class="panel-body">
          Please Upload IRIS File <br/>
            <br/> <br/>
     <form action="convertfile1.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <input type="file" name="file" id="file" > &nbsp; <br/><br/><input type="submit" class="btn btn-info " value="Generate ASB Format">
    </form>
          </div>
        </div>
         
    </div>
    
</body>
</html>
```

```
    <?php
    $file="iris.txt";

    $fopen = fopen($file, 'r');

    $fread = fread($fopen,filesize($file));

    fclose($fopen);

    $remove = "\n";

    $split = explode($remove, $fread);

    $array[] = null;
    $tab = ",";

    foreach ($split as $string)
    {
        $row = explode($tab, $string);
        array_push($array,$row);
    }
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($array);
    echo "</pre>";
?>
```

My code is not showing anything in an array, it is blank. How could I get data in different rows in an array with the try-catch pattern in PHP? After that file will be converted and download by any user as.CSV file in the end.

Please help me out.

Comment: `$file="/home/abc/Downloads/";` this is a folder path, not a file

Comment: @rndus2r, oh sorry dear I forget, now I correct it.

Comment: will you help me please

Comment: `$array[] = null;` is not the correct way to define an array. `$array = [];`

Comment: Sir, I try but not works array is blank.

Comment: Besided that `explode` gives you an array back, you will need to loop through that aswell. If it's still empty then you're messing up with something else before. Add some text data to your question, I guess not many will download it.

Comment: I tried this code and array works i can see the output of the text file in array. Is your txt file in the same folder as your project file?

Comment: @pr1nc3, No, it is in the downloads folder.

Comment: Depending on how you run the PHP script the interpreter does not have access to any files outside of the web root (e.g. wwwroot/htdocs). Try copying the file there.

Comment: Move it in the folder you are having the project and you will see that it will run perfectly. If you want to access it from another folder then you need absolute path.

Comment: @rndus Sir, I don't know much about arrays will you please help me in brief with the code. So I can get out from this. I never used files before.

Comment: @pr1nc3, dear I have put the file in project folder now but I got this type of error Warning: fopen(IRISFILEFORANZUPLOAD.txt): failed to open stream: No such file or directory. Now what can I do, and also It will showing array as blanked again.

Comment: IRISFILEFORANZUPLOAD.txt is another file that the one you have in your project.  Are you sure that the names match? in the variable $file you must put inside the "" the EXACT name of the file you are having in your folder.

Comment: Well it's pretty clear with the error "No such file" the fopen function cannot find or access the file, hard to say when you don't show us the complete code you're using to access the file.

Comment: File name is this :
 
IRISFILEFORANZUPLOAD.txt

Comment: Then you need to use `$file="IRISFILEFORANZUPLOAD.txt";` in your PHP code obviously :)

Comment: @xander does not work Sir, I used this 
These are all the errors on my screen:-
Warning: fopen(IRISFILEFORANZUPLOAD.txt): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /opt/lampp/htdocs/karenkay/php/convertfile1.php on line 5

Warning: filesize(): stat failed for IRISFILEFORANZUPLOAD.txt in /opt/lampp/htdocs/karenkay/php/convertfile1.php on line 7

Warning: fread() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /opt/lampp/htdocs/karenkay/php/convertfile1.php on line 7

Comment: Warning: fclose() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /opt/lampp/htdocs/karenkay/php/convertfile1.php on line 9

Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 
        )

)

Comment: change your first line in php to "$file = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];", hope this help

Comment: @AkkapongKajornwongwattana, Hello mate it's not working. I don't know why this happening.

Comment: Can you print parameter $file after change to $file = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];